# What happens if the file system in /etc/fstab entries is deleted by the user?

Tags: mount, fstab

I am trying to share a directory between my Ubuntu host with my macOS Virtualbox guest using NFS. I am following this guide: [SettingUpNFSHowTo - Community Help Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpNFSHowTo).

> To save us from retyping this after every reboot we add the following
>   line to /etc/fstab
>   /home/users    /export/users   none    bind  0  0

I am hesitant because I don't know what happens when I accidently delete the former folder from my host. I just wanna share a source code repo and may forget to delete the entry from fstab before deleting the repo directory itself.
Will it stop my host from booting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, if the entry isn't your root, you will be prompted to continue, I usually get an unusual loading screen, but you will boot.

I've never tried removing the root entry from the fstab, but if my escapades in NFS roots are anything to go by, you'll probably get a kernel panic, or at best, a drop to your initramfs busybox CLI to manually mount your root partition.